# Why is the a etiquette moved outside of its child and of different size?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem I cannot solve, it seems weird to me but I hope you guys can figure out a solution.

The thing is, some a etiquettes of my website (not all of them) are smaller in size than the img they contain, and they're displaced, which affects the layout as it looks like a bottom margin.

Here's a picture of it, if you need any other info just let me know. [image: My Website problem]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
img{vertical-align:bottom}
```

I'll give further explanation if this works.

Comment: Basically, images are by default aligned to the baseline. The baseline allows for characters such as `gjpqy` to drop below the line. By setting `vertical-align:bottom`, you are forcing images to align to the very bottom of the line. As long as the images are taller than the line-height, they will fit perfectly.